# Square of stars and numbers in java

Tags: java, for-loop

I have to create a method that results as below:

```
for n = 5

* 2 3 4 5
* * 3 4 5
* * * 4 5
* * * * 5
* * * * *
```

My attempt:

```
int n = 5;

for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    String row = "";
    for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
        row += "*";
            if (i==j) {
                System.out.print(row + "\n");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Result is:

```
*
**
***
****
*****
```

Comment: You're like... *literally* halfway there.  What do you think should be printed if `i != j`?

Answer (score 1):

Anna, you should do something like this:

```
int n = 5;

for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    String row = "";
    //This for build the entire output var
    for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
        if (i<j) { // if you are behind or in the line it receive a "*"
            row+=String.valueOf(j+1);
        } else { //if you are not it receive the number wich is j+1
            row += "*";
        }
    }
    System.out.println(row + "\n"); //Print the entire line
}
```

In your implementation you was printing only in the match line, and never printing anything else in the first iteration loop.
Is it clear for you?

Comment: Yes, it's clear, now I understand this code :D thank you

Comment: only it should start from star so it is little modification  int n = 5;

  for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
      String row = "";
      //This for build the entire output var
      for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
          if (i<j) { // if you are behind or in the line it receive a "*"
              row += String.valueOf(j+1);
          } else { //if you are not it receive the number wich is j+1
              row+="*";
          }
      }
      System.out.println(row + "\n"); //Print the entire line
  }
 }

Comment: @Anna Corrected to match with your first description of the wanted output.

Comment: Please, do not teach with using string concatenation. In general cases this is bad practic, especially within loops. Anna could think that it is ok and use it in another palce as well. Possible variants: 1. string concatenation with maximum 2 string like "a" + "b"; 2. StringBuilder - for any time; 3. String.format() - like light version of StringBuilder.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're trying to solve a quiz.
What you're looking for is a pattern to that grid, and your answer isn't too far off.

Looking back at your original sample:
When X (horizontal) is greater than Y (vertical) we print X, otherwise we print an asterisk.  And there's a space in between each element.

```
public class Main9 {
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    String row = "";
    for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
        if (i > j) {
            // Now we should append X (or i in this case) to the row
            // Adding 1 to the base 0 integer
            //  and appending with a space
            row += (i+1)+" ";
        } else {
            // Otherwise just add "* "
            row += "* ";
        }
    }
    // Now that we're done with the j-loop we can print out the row
    System.out.println(row);
}
```

}

Comment: Thank you for help :D only i changed from i to j -> row +=(j+1) +

Answer (score 0):

You could do it without any string concatenation and not using other objects. Let me offer my soulution:

```
int n = 5;

for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
   for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) 
        System.out.print(j <= i ? "*" : ("" + (j + 1)));

    System.out.println();
}
```

Comment: Hello, for line "System.out.print(j <= i ? "*" : (j + 1));" eclipcse show error:
"Unresolved compilation problem: Incompatible conditional operand types String and int"